# git, wrong reference to an old deleted app

Tags: git

thanks for taking the time to help. i am a newcommer to git, but i have spent two full days trying to solve my problems. all i want at the end is have a folder on my desktop where i can edit the code and apply the changes to the facebook page. 
Everytime i solve something, something else cause a problem, now it must be a mess so i will start with the last problem (error message) i got and work my way back to the top.
i was simply following this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook and i created a clone that shows on my desktop. when i type git remote, i get heroku.
but when i typed $ git commit -am "changed greeting" i had to assign the folder boiling-badlands-5761 (that contains all the files) to apply the changes then when i type git push heroku i get
 !  Your key with fingerprint 33:91:89:4d:cf:65:b8:31:7d:c8:69:6f:cb:b9:1d:15 is
 not authorized to access furious-robot-218.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
the thing is furious-robot-218 is an old app i deleted one day ago. (like i said i spent a fair amount of time searching and trying things including creating new apps hoping it would give me a fresh start)
Could you tell me what is the command to simply assign all the changes to the right folder i did that:git add boiling-badlands-5761/
and it gave me that:

```
            C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git add boiling-badlands-5761/
            C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git status
            # On branch new-main-branch
            #
            # Initial commit
            #
            # Changes to be committed:
            #   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
            #
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/.gitmodules
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/AppInfo.php
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/Readme.md
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/channel.html
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/images/fpo-picture.gif
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/images/get-started-bg.jpg
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/images/header-sketch.png
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/images/picture-sketch.png
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/images/samples-bg.png
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/images/sprites.png
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/index.php
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/base.css
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/mobile.css
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/reset.css
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/screen.css
            #       new file:   boiling-badlands-5761/utils.php
            #
            # Untracked files:
            #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
            #
            #       Any Video Converter Professional.lnk
            #       Audacity.lnk
            #       Continuer l'installation Daemon Tools Lite.lnk
            #       GoldWave.lnk
            #       Notepad++.lnk
            #       cmd.exe
            #       desktop.ini
```

then

```
            C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git commit -am "changed greeting"
            [new-main-branch (root-commit) dc24904] changed greeting
             Committer: unknown <jeroe@jeroe-PC.(none)>
            Your name and email address were configured automatically based
            on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
            You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:
                git config --global user.name "Your Name"
                git config --global user.email you@example.com
            After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:
                git commit --amend --reset-author
             17 files changed, 924 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/.gitmodules
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/AppInfo.php
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/Readme.md
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/channel.html
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/images/fpo-picture.gif
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/images/get-started-bg.jpg
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/images/header-sketch.png
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/images/picture-sketch.png
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/images/samples-bg.png
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/images/sprites.png
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/index.php
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/base.css
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/mobile.css
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/reset.css
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/stylesheets/screen.css
             create mode 100644 boiling-badlands-5761/utils.php
```

git status gives me that:

```
            C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git status
            # On branch new-main-branch
            # Untracked files:
            #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
            #
            #       Any Video Converter Professional.lnk
            #       Audacity.lnk
            #       Continuer l'installation Daemon Tools Lite.lnk
            #       GoldWave.lnk
            #       Notepad++.lnk
            #       cmd.exe
            #       desktop.ini
            nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

and git log that

```
            C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git log
            commit dc2490455c28f930c9395e793cc4e93265cabde6
            Author: unknown <jeroe@jeroe-PC.(none)>
            Date:   Tue Jul 31 18:35:24 2012 +0200
                changed greeting
```

could you help me cause i really have no idea where to look now. the more i try different commands the more i mess it up.
for now i just want to assign the changes to the right folder. 
thanks  in advance

---

thats great thank you very much i just have one last important question. after doing the commands you said it applied the code but i was wondering if i had to redo those steps everytime i want to edit the code. so i simply closed the cmd and opened again to enter the git comit -am then git push heroku and then again it refered to this old app called furious robot
is there a way to edit the right folder and code without having to type all the commands you gave me. because it would be a very very tedious job if so.

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first you seem to have initialized a git repo in your Desktop folder:

```
C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git add boiling-badlands-5761/
C:\Users\jeroe\Desktop>git status ;# this returns output
```

This is not what you want to do. Try using the `git clone` command [mentioned in the heroku docs here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#1-fetch-your-apps-source-code) first, then `cd` into that directory after you clone it. Second, before you do anything else, issue these commands (of course replace `<Your_Name>` and `<your_email>` with your name and email, respectively):

```
git config --global user.name "<Your_Name>"
git config --global user.email <your_email>
```

This will prevent the "author unknown" commit problem you were experiencing next:

```
 Author: unknown <jeroe@jeroe-PC.(none)>
```

Try these first. If the heroku push problem persists, we'll address that too, but until you've got a clone that 1) isn't your Desktop directory, and 2) isn't saving commits without committer information, there's no point in doing anything else.

Once you have the new clone mentioned above, move the contents of the boiling-badlands-5761 into it. Don't move the whole directory, just the files. Then after you issue the `git config` commands, try `git add .` from the new clone, and `git commit`.

Comment: sorry, it might sound stupid but what do you mean by "then cd that directory after you clone it". i dont want to be a pain i am just afraid to mess it up even more if i miss a step. thanks

Comment: No worries; you're not being a pain. `cd` is a terminal command. So after you issue `git clone`, you want to change directory (i.e. `cd`) into that directory. In your case, it's going to likely be `cd boiling-badlands-5761/` in your terminal.

Comment: thats great thank you very much i just have one last important question. after doing the commands you said it applied the code but i was wondering if i had to redo those steps everytime i want to edit the code. so i simply closed the cmd and opened again to enter the git comit -am then git push heroku and then again it refered to this old app called furious robot is there a way to edit the right folder and code without having to type all the commands you gave me. because it would be a very very tedious job if so.

thanks again